# using of <a href> in strings.properties file

Tags: asp.net

I need to open a .txt file new new browser using  from"str.properties file in ASP.Net

I am using click here.

I placed the test.txt in the same folder where I have my str.properties file.

I am getting error while accessing the path.

Comment: Seems like you have problem with your file path, please have a look : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

The path that your link will point to will be relative to the Page it is on. It is not relative to where your str.properties file is.

If you have a page MyPage.aspx that has that link at root level, you should keep your .txt file too in your root level folder.